# Converting SQL Left JOIN to Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, join

I have been wrangling with this for a while, but I just can't find a solid example to work from so I'm turning hopefully to the experts.  Appreciation in advance for any help.

I have a working SQL query that I need to convert to Linq. Initially, I had a simple linq query driving an MSChart (line chart) that showed the daily ranking of an item in a list.  Unfortunately, MSChart doesn't drop days with null values off the chart, but just connects them to the next day with a non-null value, so I have to replace the nulls with 0s.

The following query does this via a Left, Self Join against the table, where I just grab the distinct list of days (which will include all days).  I know I could set up an ancillary table with a list of all days as well, but this should be just as effective in all cases.  The SQL that follows works perfectly in SSMS for a specific book/List combination:

```
select L2.date, ISNULL(L1.ranking,0)  
from (select distinct date from ListItem where ListID = 1) L2  
Left join ListItem L1 on L2.date = L1.date and L1.BookID = 1 and L1.ListID = 1  
order by date
```

This returns a list of all dates and rankings, with a 0 ranking for any date that no ranking exists.  Now in order to bind the chart to this, I believe converting to Linq is the best course.

I would post my attempts so far, but I fear they are woefully wrong.  If any more information is necessary, please let me know.

Thanks.

-Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var distinctDates = 
    ListItems
        .Where(li => li.ListId == 1)
        .Select(li => li.date)
        .Distinct();

var list1 = 
    ListItems
        .Where(li => li.BookID == 1 && li.ListID == 1);

var results = 
    distinctDates
        .Join(
            list1,
            d => d,
            li1 => li1.date,
            (d, li1) => new{ date = d, ranking = li1.ranking ?? 0 }
        )
        .OrderBy(x => x.date);
```

(Made a few changes since 1st rev.)

Comment: This looks very close except I'm getting an error on the last line of the Join on "ranking = li1.ranking ?? 0". It says "Operator "??" cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' or type 'int'

Comment: Okay, solved that issue by adding (int?) in front of "ranking = li1.ranking ?? 0".  But it still returns the same set as before, with the null dates missing from the set.  No worse, but no better yet.  Nevertheless, the construction looks good so I suspect we're close.

Comment: Just inside a year late, I finally realized I had gotten this working.  Belated thanks, spender.